# Web scraping with beautiful soup, entering all links and getting information

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am trying to open each company from StackOverflow companies and get specific informations(such as the whole description).Is there an easy way to do that using Beautiful Soup?For now I am getting the links of the companies of the first page.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get('https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/companies')
src = r.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(src,'lxml')
urls=[]

for h2_tag in soup.find_all("h2"):
    a_tag = h2_tag.find('a')
    urls.append(a_tag.attrs['href'])

print(urls)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bsoup

for i in range(0, 5):
    site_source = requests.get(
        f"https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/companies?pg={i}"
    ).content
    soup = bsoup(site_source, "html.parser")
    company_list = soup.find("div", class_="company-list")
    company_block = company_list.find_all("div", class_="grid--cell fl1 text")
    for company in company_block:
        if company.find("a"):
            company_url = company.find("a").attrs["href"]
            base_url = "https://stackoverflow.com"
            company_source = requests.get(base_url + company_url).content
            company_soup = bsoup(company_source, "html.parser")
            company_info = company_soup.find("div", id="company-name-tagline")
            print("Name: ", company_info.find("h1").text)
            print("Info: ", company_info.find("p").text)
            print()
```

I am basically looping through the page 1 to page 5 and and getting the link of each company and then going to the company name and printing out the name and description of it.

My output

```
Name:  BigCommerce
Info:  Think BIG

Name:  Facebook
Info:  Our mission is to give people the power to build community and bring the world closer together.   

Name:  trivago N.V.
Info:  A diverse team of talents that make a blazing fast accommodation search powered by cutting-edge tech and entrepreneurial innovation. 

Name:  General Dynamics UK
Info:  General Dynamics UK is one of the UK’s leading defence companies, and an important supplier to the UK Ministry of Defence (MoD).   

Name:  EDF
Info:  EDF is leading the transition to a cleaner, low emission electric future, tackling climate change and helping Britain reach net zero.

Name:  Radix DLT
Info:  Delivering Scalable Trust.
```

Answer (score 0):

There is, you can scroll through the first page, then go to the second one using selenium to click on the 2nd page button, and pass on the page source every time, that should work i assume

Comment: Thank you for your answer.I actually meant that I want to open each company's link  get the information i need and then go back and do the same for the next company(i get how i can loop through pages) .Thank you anyway! :)

Comment: you can check my updated answer i am doing what you mention which is open each company's link to get the information